# Can XHTML nest more XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, embed, document

It's legal to nest SVG documents inside XHTML documents; but is it legal to nest XHTML documents inside other XHTML documents in the same fashion?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Nested document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>This is a sample</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `html` element is only allowed as root element of the document.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using `<iframe>` *(though not recommended and should be avoided)*.

Comment: As far as I know, standard uses of `<iframe>` mandate the `src` attribute and will not support nesting a document.